# How to install latest node version on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I want to install the latest node (v6.2.0 at the time of writing) on Ubuntu. But as I do

```
sudo apt-get nodejs
```

This installed v0.10.37.

Can you please help me in installing the latest version of node js and also npm latest version?

Comment: That's probably the latest version available in your package manger. Maybe checkout [How can I update my nodeJS to the latest version?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara  how can i completely remove node from my system. its all mess in here with multiple node_modules.

Answer (score 10):

This is very simple, 
Grab the Linux node distribution from here:
https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.2.0/

Open Terminal and type below command:

```
sudo tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xzf ~/Downloads/node-v6.2.0-linux-x64.tar.gz

ls -l /usr/local/bin/node
```

That`s it.

Now check your node version by typing:

```
node -v
npm -v
```

One can install any version of node in Ubuntu using above steps.

Comment: Since node is installed @ /usr/local/bin/ we can use follwing command to remove node completely: rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node. This should work.

Answer (score 7):

There is [official instruction](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Follow https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x to read shell script before execute above commands.
You always must to know what you run, especially by sudo.

Comment: after running these commands, node -v gives No such file or directory

Comment: in ubuntu it becomes `nodejs`. Some naming conflicts.

Comment: this also gives me 0.10.37 older version.

Comment: Your legacy nodejs is still here. Run `/usr/bin/nodejs -v` and remove `/usr/local/bin/nodejs` after success.. I don't know way to correct uninstall legacy nodejs, may be `apt-get remove nodejs-legacy`

Answer (score 5):

To remove previous version use command

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
```

and then for latest version

```
sudo n latest
```

Or for stable version

```
sudo n stable
```

Answer (score 4):

## Any version of node install is very easy

Just click [Node.js](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md)  scroll down and go ***Installation instructions*** and chose which version you want to install

To Install 12.x version of node:

1. Open your terminal [Ctrl+Alt+t]
2. execute below command

**Using Ubuntu**

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

## or

**Using Debian, as root**

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 2):

By far the most convenient way to install and manage node versions on your machine is the Node Version Manager a.k.a [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). Just follow the installation instructions in the repo and after you have it installed run

```
nvm install 6.2.0
```

Comment: I have installed node v6.2.0. How do i install npm(the latest version)

Comment: run `npm -g install npm` twice

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest installing through package manager to make sure it installs with accurate dependencies.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Also, use NPM

```
 sudo apt-get install npm
```

to install modules, like so:

```
npm install express
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the package through the official download page, in a .deb format. Go ahead and grab the newest version here:

https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest/

Just go ahead and download your desired version and double-click on the downloaded .deb file, and you're good to go. npm comes with nodejs, btw.

**RECOMMENDED READING**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm

**EDIT**

If you wish to completely reinstall nodejs, check out the script located here:

https://gist.github.com/brock/5b1b70590e1171c4ab54

and check out this:

[How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

It says Mac OSX, but it'll work perfectly fine in ubuntu, too.

Comment: I can't to find `.deb` download by your link

Comment: Also `sudo rm -rf $HOME/{local,lib,include,node*,npm,.npm*}` row in  `reinstall script`. Why want it to force(and silent) remove my `~/lib` folder?

Answer (score 1):

### Install the snap package

The easiest method to install Node.js on Ubuntu is to use the snap package. Just search for node on *Ubuntu Software* store and install the first one.

[image: Node.js on Ubuntu Software]

Or if you prefer command line:

```
sudo snap install node --classic
```

---

### Alternate method: NVM

If you can't use snaps for some reason, like from a WSL environment, then [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (NVM) is the way to go. It's safer than upgrading the node packages in Ubuntu to unsupported versions from PPAs or 3rd party repos, which may cause conflicts or breakages in apt package management system. Compared to NVM, manual installations from tarballs are harder to maintain and upgrade. Follow these steps to install the latest node using NVM:

#### Step 1: Install NVM

Run this command in *Terminal*:

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
```

#### Step 2: Install node

Once NVM installation is complete, close and reopen *Terminal*. Then run this command:

```
nvm install node
```

#### Step 3: Check node version

Run these commands:

```
node --version
npm --version
```

If everything went well, you'll see the latest node and npm versions as output. That's all, node is installed and ready to run!

---

Note: This question is similar to the AskUbuntu question ["How do I install the latest version of node.js?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js/) and [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js/953362#953362) equally applies. I'm reproducing my answer here to ensure a full complete answer exists rather than just a link.

Comment: @Shqear You've to close and reopen Terminal for the nvm command to be available

Answer (score 1):

depends on what version of latest nodejs you want to install
if LTS version or current latest version, then from PPA

**latest LTS version**

```
apt-get install curl python-software-properties
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
apt-get install nodejs
```

**current latest version**

```
apt-get install curl python-software-properties
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
apt-get install nodejs
```

source: https://codesposts.com/ydOAwynW

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install -y nano git curl vim htop gnupg2 && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash - && sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations! In your specific case, it would be much more convenient if you would make a line break instead of using several `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Install NodeJS 14x and npm 7x in Ubuntu 2020 LTS

- Install Nodesource: `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -`
- Install NodeJS: `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`
- Install latest npm: `npm install -g npm@latest`
- For certain npm packages to run: `sudo apt install build-essential`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using a single line command is `sudo snap install node --classic`

It installs the latest stable node version from snap store.